# Match at least 3 words in any order from some 5 words

Tags: regex, oracle, string-matching, regexp-like

I have a group of words:

```
"dog", "car", "house", "work", "cat"
```

I need to be able to match at least 3 of them in a text, for example:

```
"I always let my cat and dog at the animal nursery when I go to work by car"
```

Here I want to match the regex because it matches at least 3 words (4 words here):

```
"cat", "dog", "car" and "work"
```

### EDIT 1

I want to use it with *Oracle*'s ***`regexp_like`*** function

### EDIT 2

I also need it to work with consecutive words

Comment: I want to use it with oracle's regexp_like function

Comment: Please clarify if “dog dog dog” should be a match (all answers so far would match this)

Comment: Must the solution use `regexp_like`?

Comment: Or any oracle regex function that gets the job done

Comment: I personally favor that every word only gets matched once

Comment: then “dog dog dog” should be a match (favor != require)

Comment: Do you need exact word matches? What if your input string contains the word 'dogs' - does that match 'dog'? How about capitalization: 'Work is great......' - does 'Work' match 'work'? How about compound words - does 'dogwood' (a kind of tree) match 'dog'? How about 'doghouse' - does that count twice (it matches both 'dog' and 'house')? Did you even think about any of these questions? If you didn't, don't you need to - before you think about any possible solution?

Comment: @mathguy You are absulutely right about this, for now I need an exact match

Comment: OK - you still need to define "exact match". For example, in the answer you marked Correct, a search word will not be considered an exact match if it is immediately followed by a comma, period or question mark (if it is at the end of a sentence) - is that OK? Probably not. You need to give a complete definition of "exact match", then test the solutions to make sure they match that definition in all cases.

Comment: Yes, you're right in that this question does need to be much better defined for the best solution to be found. What characters could appear in the input, when does a word count as a match and when does it not, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Oracle's `regexp_like` doesn't support non-capturing groups and word boundaries, the following expression can be used:

```
^((.*? )?(dog|car|house|work|cat)( |$)){3}.*$
```

[Try it out here](https://regex101.com/r/MtAJbV/3).

Alternatively, a larger but arguably cleaner solution is:

```
^(.*? )?(dog|car|house|work|cat) .*?(dog|car|house|work|cat) .*?(dog|car|house|work|cat)( .*)?$
```

[Try it out here](https://regex101.com/r/qPTPOB/4).

NOTE: These will both match the same word used multiple times, e.g. "dog dog dog".

**EDIT:** To address the concerns over punctuation, a small modification can be made. It isn't perfect, but should match 99% of situations involving punctuation (but won't match e.g. `!dog`):

```
^((.*? )?(dog|car|house|work|cat)([ ,.!?]|$)){3}.*$
```

[Try it out here](https://regex101.com/r/MtAJbV/4)

Comment: Look at the following link : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/ap_posix.htm#g693775

Comment: @CallumWatkins The link was for OP actually. But it is the list of regular expression options available using `REGEXP_LIKE` on Oracle

Comment: @YassinHajaj I see, do you know why my expression may not be working in the oracle environment yourself?

Comment: @CallumWatkins I think it would be the `(?:...)` part of it because I can't see it anywhere in the list

Comment: @FrancisEisenhower I've updated my answer to include a regex that might now work within Oracle's regexp_like.

Comment: It still doesn't match :(

Comment: @FrancisEisenhower Even with the third one I added?

Comment: Yes it matches but less by one, I mean here with 4 it doesn't match but with 3 it matches

Comment: @FrancisEisenhower I'm testing it with 4 and it still works, you could try changing `{3}` to `{3,}`, but I don't think you should have to. It works for me with 3 or more.

Comment: The last regex seems to work fine. [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8167bb/1). Best of luck.

Comment: I guess with oracle's regex is different, thanks by the way, I don't have enough reputation to upvote sorry . . .

Comment: @FrancisEisenhower I just noticed that it may not work with consecutive words, I'm working on it now.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I tried out with my tests, it didn't work with consecutive words

Comment: @FrancisEisenhower Try my new one

Comment: This will match “dog dog dog”

Comment: @Bohemian OP has expressed no concern regarding the same word being matched multiple times to me. If this is a problem, good luck solving it with regex.

Comment: Is this problem very difficult to tackle?

Comment: @FrancisEisenhower I, personally, am unaware of any way to get around that problem using purely regex, especially considering the incredible lack of features in Oracle's regex engine.

Comment: OK thanks anyway, this would be sufficient for me right now

Comment: @FrancisEisenhower MT0's answer now seems like the go-to, but if you decide to continue using this regex for any reason, know that I have updated it since you last copied it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution that doesn't use regular expressions, will exclude repeated words and the words to match can be passed in as a bind parameter in a collection:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/34627/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

Create a collection type to store a list of words:

```
CREATE TYPE StringList IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50)
/
```

Create a PL/SQL function to split a delimited string into the collection:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_String(
  i_str    IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN StringList DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_result       StringList := StringList();
  p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
  p_end          NUMBER(5);
  c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_str );
  c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  IF c_len > 0 THEN
    p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, p_end - p_start );
      p_start := p_end + c_ld;
      p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    END LOOP;
    IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 );
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN p_result;
END;
/
```

Create some test data:

```
CREATE TABLE test_data ( value ) AS
SELECT 'I always let my cat and dog at the animal nursery when I go to work by car' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'dog dog foo bar dog' FROM DUAL
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   test_data
WHERE  CARDINALITY(
         split_string( value, ' ' )    -- Split the string into a collection
         MULTISET INTERSECT            -- Intersect it with the input words
         StringList( 'dog', 'car', 'house', 'work', 'cat' )
       ) >= 3                          -- Check that the size of the intersection
                                       -- is at least 3 items.
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/34627/3/0)**:

```
|                                                                      VALUE |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| I always let my cat and dog at the animal nursery when I go to work by car |
```

Comment: This is a very good solution and will beat any regular expression at functionality and readability.

Comment: This solution, like all the others, ignores the subtle question of "what constitutes an exact word match." For example, it will only find one word match in the phrase "My brother has a cat, a dog and a car." - because the relevant tokens will be "cat," (with the comma) and "car." (with the period). It is very likely that the requirement would be to "match" three words in this example. No amount of clever code writing can make up for lack of clarity in the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the questions I asked in a Comment under the original post, here is one easy way to solve the problem, with a join and aggregation (using a `HAVING` condition). Note that a word like `doghouse` in the input will match both `dog` and `house`, etc. (Do read my comment under the original post!)

In the query below, both the input phrase and the words to match are hardcoded in factored subqueries (the `WITH` clause). In a serious environment, both should be in base tables, or be provided as input variables, etc.

I show how to use the standard string comparison operator `LIKE`. This can be changed to `REGEXP_LIKE`, but that is generally unneeded (and indeed a bad idea). But if you need to differentiate between 'dog' and 'dogs' (and 'dogwood'), or need case insensitive comparison, etc., you can use `REGEXP_LIKE`. The point of this solution is that you don't need to worry about matching THREE different words; if you know how to match ONE (whether full word match is needed, capitalization does or does not matter, etc.), then you can also, easily, match THREE words under the same rules.

```
with
  inputs ( input_phrase ) as (
    select
  'I always let my cat and dog at the animal nursery when I go to work by car'
    from   dual
  ),
  words ( word_to_match) as (
    select 'dog'   from dual union all
    select 'car'   from dual union all
    select 'house' from dual union all
    select 'work'  from dual union all
    select 'cat'   from dual
  )
select   input_phrase
from     inputs inner join words 
                on input_phrase like '%' || word_to_match || '%'
group by input_phrase
having   count(*) >= 3
;

INPUT_PHRASE                                                              
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
I always let my cat and dog at the animal nursery when I go to work by car
```

Comment: Nice and simple.. should perform better than others.

Comment: `I always keep my carrot houseplant at the cattery` would also be matched.

Comment: @MT0 - I said the same in my Comment to the OP - I used 'dogwood' as an example similar to your 'carrot'. "Match whole words only" is an incomplete clarification though; how about plural forms of the desired words, is that OK? How about capitalization? etc. As I stated explicitly in my Answer: IF you know how to address all these additional requirements (with REGEXP, or in any other manner), then you can use the technique I showed to extend from matching ONE word to matching as many as needed. Since that was my only goal, I didn't worry about the rest.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution will exclude repeated matches, doesn't use regular expressions (though you can if you like), and doesn't use PL/SQL.

```
WITH match_list ( match_word ) AS (
    SELECT 'dog' AS match_word FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'work' FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'car' FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'house' FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'cat' FROM dual
)
SELECT phrase, COUNT(*) AS unique_match_cnt, SUM(match_cnt) AS total_match_cnt
     , LISTAGG(match_word, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY match_word ) AS unique_matches
  FROM (
    SELECT pt.phrase, ml.match_word, COUNT(*) AS match_cnt
      FROM phrase_table pt INNER JOIN match_list ml
        ON ' ' || LOWER(pt.phrase) || ' ' LIKE '%' || ml.match_word || '%'
     GROUP BY pt.phrase, ml.match_word
) GROUP BY phrase
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3;
```

The key is putting the words you want to match into a table or common table expression/subquery. If you like you can use `REGEXP_LIKE()` in place of `LIKE` though I think that would be more expensive. Skip `LISTAGG()` if you're not using Oracle 11g or higher, or if you don't actually need to know which words were matched, and skip `LOWER()` if you want a case-sensitive match.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't need to match different words.

```
(?:\b(?:dog|car|house|work|cat)\b.*?){3}
```

I don't know if this works in your environment.

EDIT: I didn't see there is another answer almost like this one.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't match with oracle's regexp_like function

Comment: Sadly Oracle regular expressions don't support word boundaries.